# Json.Net deserialising DateTimes inconsistently

Tags: c#, json, date, datetime, json.net

I am having trouble deserialising datetimes with Json.Net 6.0.3 (I can replicate the issue on 6.0.6). The code is run in .Net 4.5 on Windows 8.1, and the culture is en-GB.

This demonstrates the problem:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var d1 = new DateTimeOffset(2014, 12, 15, 18, 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
var obj = new {
    time = d1
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(json);

var jo = JObject.Parse(json);

Console.WriteLine(jo.Value<string>("time") + " // jo.Value<string>(\"time\")");
Console.WriteLine(jo["time"] + " // jo[\"time\"]");
```

the output:

```
{
    "time": "2014-12-15T18:00:00+01:00"
}
12/15/2014 17:00:00 // jo.Value<string>("time")
15/12/2014 17:00:00 // jo["time"]
```

The date times are different depending on how the JObject is accessed - one is MM/DD/YYYY DD/MM/YYYY. Why is this?

I don't need them to be in a specific format: the problem is that the format changes. I have a lot of legacy code that parses the datetime string sourced from Json.Net. The code will also run on different computers around the world, maybe with different cultures.

Is there a way to make Json.Net always return datetimes in the same format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that the two lines do different things:

```
jo["time"]
```

Is (ultimately) writing an actual `DateTime` value to the console. As [@JonSkeet points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27529668/json-net-deserialising-datetimes-inconsistently#comment43488423_27529922), you're actually writing a `JValue` to the console--[`JValue.ToString` just calls the wrapped value's `ToString` method though](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JValue.cs#L793), which in your case is `DateTime.ToString()`.

In other words:

- Calling `Console.WriteLine` and passing an instance of `JValue` uses the overload of `Console.WriteLine` that takes an `object`.
- That overload calls `.ToString()` on the `JValue`
- Which then calls `.ToString()` on the underlying type (in your case a `DateTime`)

So you're going to get whatever format is the default for your current culture. More specifically, you're going to get the `DateTime` formatted with the "G" specifier in your current culture.

The more interesting bit is the `jo.Value<string>("time")` line. [Under the hood](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/Extensions.cs#L279), JSON.NET is converting the underlying `DateTime` to a string using the following:

```
Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(string), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This, of course, produces an entirely *different* string, since it's explicitly using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

The takeaway from this is that your best bet is probably to retrieve the date as a `DateTime`, and then format it the exact way you want it, to avoid any ambiguity:

```
DateTime dt = jo.Value<DateTime>("time");
string dateTimeSTring = dt.ToString(/* whatever format you always want */);
```

Comment: @JonSkeet: Well, yes, I've oversimplified it, but `JValue`'s `ToString` method calls the underlying value's (in this case a `DateTime`) `ToString` method.

Comment: Right. I would un-oversimplify it if I were you. The basic premise is fine (which is why I've abandoned my own answer) but it's good to be precise about this when conversions are involved all over the place.